# Java multithreaded post method with proxy (using Jsoup)

Tags: java, multithreading, post, proxy, jsoup

Hi i need to know how to use proxy with Jsoup in multithreaded application. When i try this:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", myproxy); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", myport);
```

It's set proxy for all threat i made, i need to each threat use own proxy. This GET method work good:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("addres", port));
URL url = new URL("address");
URLConnection connect = url.openConnection(proxy);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

String tmp;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((tmp=br.readLine())!=null) sb.append(tmp);

Document c = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString());
```

But I don't know how to send POST method using proxy in each threat with Jsoup. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JSoup docs](http://jsoup.org/):

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

So, basically Jsoup is created for *extracting* data. However, it is still possible to execute `POST` requests but it is not as straight forward as for `GET` requests.

```
ocument doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.facebook.com")
                   .data("field1", "value2")
                   .data("field2", "value2")
                   .userAgent("Mozilla") // Optional
                   .post();
```

In order to work this out with a proxy the following can be used:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<proxy-host>");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<proxy-port>");
```

Or, for the `https` equivalent:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "<proxy-host>");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "<proxy-port>");
```

There are a bunch of other questions on StackOverflow regarding this matter. Check out:

- [How to add Proxy-support to JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482748/how-to-add-proxy-support-to-jsoup-html-parser)
- [How to post data into website using JSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012399/how-to-post-data-into-website-using-jsoup)

Comment: Actually you can Post using Jsoup. You can login a webpage and save the session cookie for further browsing, I'm doing it in one of my applications. But I reached this post looking for the Proxy solution, I have the very same issue