# How to configure httpClient to jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, httpclient

I am trying to set http client to Jsoup to use TOR as proxy, but I can't find a way to set client to Jsoup, I'm wondering how can I do that knowing that Jsoup doesn't need an httpClient configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add proxy support to Jsoup (HTML parser)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482748/how-to-add-proxy-support-to-jsoup-html-parser)

Answer (score 2):

Jsoup doesn't use HttpClient, but you can set the proxy using:

```
// Setup proxy
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
        InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", 80));

// Setup the authenticator
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                "password".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

// Send a request using the proxy
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/")
        .proxy(proxy)
        .get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, for the proxy i am using a username and password, does the createUnresolved supports more parameters ?