# Jsoup html parse region language settings java

Tags: java, proxy, jsoup, html-parsing, region

How can I parse HTML data like I were in other country?

I've tried to use proxy (code):

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "some proxy");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "some port");
```

but it doesn't work properly. I still get data in my country language.

I've also tried using VPN, but when I do my program (Jsoup parser) doesn't download anything.

EDIT:

Thanks for your time, the marked answer helped me to solve the problem. The complete solution I found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8445790/6521784) .

Comment: You mean download the page in a different locale and parse it?

Comment: I mean get html of the page as I were in diffrerent locate. The website automatically locates my location and sets language, but I need it in other language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the site you're trying to download. If the site is using IP geolocation, the only solution is to use appropiate proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433296/1608594

If the site is only using HTTP headers to determine language, you can send  `Accept-Language`, `Accept-Charset` and `Accept-Encoding` headers with the proper values. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields