# Setting proxy to use JSOUP fails

Tags: java, url, proxy, web-crawler, jsoup

I try to set the proxy to conduct the scrapping google new search .

However, it appears the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.jsoup.Connection.proxy.userAgent.ignoreHttpErrors.followRedirects.timeout.ignoreContentType.get
    at javaapplication27.JavaApplication27.main(JavaApplication27.java:47)
```

RED LINE ERROR-->

> cannot find symbol .Symbol :method proxy( proxy )
>
> location:interface connection

on this line:

```
 Document document = Jsoup.connect(string+"&start="+(j+0)*10)
        .proxy(proxy)
        .userAgent(userAgent)
        .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .timeout(100000)
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .get();
```

_

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(                                      //
    Proxy.Type.HTTP,                                      //
    InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", 8080) //
);
for (int j=0;j<3;j++) {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(string+"&start="+(j+0)*10)
        .proxy(proxy)
        .userAgent(userAgent)
        .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .timeout(100000)
        .ignoreContentType(true)
        .get();
    Elements links = document.select( ".r>a");
    ......
 }
```

My imports

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
```

How to fix?

Comment: Take a look at this post may help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482748/how-to-add-proxy-support-to-jsoup-html-parser

Comment: this sounds like a compilation error but I cannot reproduce

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto should i post the full code?

Comment: At which line and when (compilation or runtime) do you get this error exactly?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.jsoup.Connection.proxy.userAgent.ignoreHttpErrors.followRedirects.timeout.ignoreContentType.get
 at javaapplication27.JavaApplication27.main(JavaApplication27.java:47)
Java Result: 1

Comment: `Document document = Jsoup.connect(string+"&start="+(j+0)*10).proxy(proxy).userAgent(userAgent). ignoreHttpErrors(true).followRedirects(true).timeout(100000).ignoreContentType(true).get();`<--error in this line

Answer (score 1):

The `.proxy()` method was first available in [jsoup 1.9.1](https://jsoup.org/news/release-1.9.1). What version are you using?

Also when I copied your code to test it, I found there are invisible zero-width spaces throughout which could be causing the syntax errors you're getting (your question talks about both missing interfaces and syntax errors).

Comment: i m using the jsoup 1.10 . I have fixed the syntax error ,but the 403 error still exists .

Comment: What 403 error? You hadn't mentioned that. At any rate that's a different problem - a forbidden response from the server you are connecting to. You can check the other existing answers for some suggestions.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/index?continue=http://www.google.com/search%253Fq%253Dstackoverflow%2526tbm%253Dnws%2526tbs%253Dcdr%2525253A1%2525252Ccd_min%2525253A5%2525252F30%2525252F2016%2525252Ccd_max%2525253A6%2525252F30%2525252F2016%2526start%253D0&q=EgTKLTckGKH5hsQFIhkA8aeDS-3IYZmr41q-m4rIMh7Uw7vC3wdLMgNyY24 at `