# Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: en.wikipedia.org - Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web, web-scraping, jsoup

I am getting error while running below code.
I tried more than 10 urls but the error is same (`java.net.UnknownHostException`).

```
public class ExtractPage {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{
        String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    }
}
```

Below is Error StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: en.wikipedia.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)
    at art.ExtractPage.main(ExtractPage.java:12)
```

I found similar problem statements over internet  but dint found the exact solution to run my code, Anyone can help ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you access the url in other ways from the machine this is running on? For example with `curl`?

Comment: I can access the url from my browser. Infact when I tried "https://www.google.com", I am getting the same exception.

Comment: Is this running inside some sort of container? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I am running the code from my office PC. so not sure about proxy/containers.

Comment: If the browser works a proxy may be configured in the browser's options. Check there.

Comment: It worked in my personal laptop. I think my organisation uses proxy that's why I was not able to connect from there. BTW thanks @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: If you discover the address of the proxy you can then see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482748/how-to-add-proxy-support-to-jsoup) for how to use it with jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

@Keshav Singh, your code is correct. There seems to be a network issue at your end.

Please find the successfully executed code.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class ExtractPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language";
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                System.out.println(doc);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do we know what could be causing the network issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set proxy along with the Jsoup as shown below

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(<website.com>)
                    .proxy(<host>, <port>)
                    .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an internet issue. please check your internet connection.