# JConsole times out when trying to connect

Tags: java, jetty, jmx, jconsole

I'm trying to use jconsole to connect to jetty. I can see that the relevant port is open with nmap, but when I try to connect to it using jconsole, the connection times out. (When I run jconsole with -debug it shows that the underlying problem is a timeout on read.) It doesn't matter which process I try to connect to. If I try to connect to some other local process that happens to be running on my laptop, it times out too.

Comment: Just an idea, what about your [Java proxy settings][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm/120802#120802

Comment: those are settings for http proxies, so they have nothing to do with connecting to other services. Also, I don't need a proxy to connect to localhost and I verify that the port is open.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started your application with *java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote ...* ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this problem? I have lately had a similar situation and in my case the problem was that the VM seems to bind to the interface identified by resolving the hostname and in my case the hostname was bound to a "bad" IP address in /etc/hosts. Having the hostname resolve to 127.0.0.1 (for example) fixed it for me.

Comment: Honestly can't remember whether I solved this, but don't think I modified `/etc/hosts` at all.