# Proxy With Java URLConnection class

Tags: java, proxy, urlconnection

I am very new with Java. I am using following code for the calling REST API, its working fine in simple environment but when I used with proxy environment Its throwing the **NullPointerException**. I found result on google that we have to set proxy setting for that. I set proxy according to that http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip42.html article but this is not working + **base64Encode( password )** creating syntax error.

```
URL url = new URL("http://examplerestapi/get/user");
URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();



in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(inputLine);
}

String res = sb.toString();
```

please help me to set proxy Host, port , username and password.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect your `NullPointerException` is occurring because `yc.getInputStream()` is returning   `null`.  You need to check that it is returning some non-null value before you attempt to create a reader to read bytes from it.

As for the proxy issue, you can pass a `Proxy` object to the connection, e.g.:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("my.proxy.example.com", 3128));
URLConnection yc = url.openConnection(proxy);
```

This might at least allow you to interrogate the Proxy and rule out potential sources for the problem (there are several, as it stands).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm) might have some useful hints for getting your proxy username and password string working properly.  The article you linked looks slightly out of date.

Comment: What about username and password?

Comment: @Gian, will the above code set the proxy configuration on jvm scope like system.setProperty ?