# Getting Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am getting Connection timed out: connect exception in java code please see below.
I have searched in google but haven't got much help,U can run this code in your machine,its complete code I am giving below.
code-

```
public class download {
    // final static int size=1024;

    public static void downloadValuationPDFReport() {
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        URLConnection uCon = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        String fAddress = null;
        URL Url = null;
        String localFileName = "abc.zip";
        String destinationDir = "H:\\";//"C:\\Users\\501301605\\Downloads";
        try {
            fAddress = "http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/downloads/ntradping.zip";
            byte[] buf;
            int byteRead = 0;
            Url = new URL(fAddress);
            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationDir + "\\" + localFileName));
            uCon = Url.openConnection();
            is = uCon.getInputStream();
            buf = new byte[1024];
            while ((byteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting some connect time out:
uCon .setConnectTimeout(VALUE);
uCon.setReadTimeout(VALUE);

Comment: @SaqibRezwan thanks for the comment,but getting same problem

Comment: Works for me properly. Firewall problem? Can you download the file directly (from a browser)?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall perchance?

Comment: @agad have it  downloaded the file properly?

Comment: @RSingh yes, file was downloaded.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup yes behind proxy,but url that is mentioned in the above code is easily accessible from browser,then why it will be blocked through code?

Comment: Why do you think that Java automatically know your browsers proxy settings?

Comment: @agad thank you very much,but I don't know why I am not able to get it though,is it could be proxy issue,but link given in code is accessible from browser

Comment: Just ran your code, it worked perfectly. So, there may be some restrictions in windows firewall. Create a new out going rule in windows firewall which allow everything. Hopefully, You will be able to download.

Comment: As @AndersR.Bystrup has written: java doesn't know your proxy settings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264889/proxy-with-java-urlconnection-class for solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that you are within a network where you are not allowed to connect directly to anything port 80; try and:

```
telnet www.novell.com 80
```

and see if you get an answer; this will probably result in a timeout as well.

More likely than not you need to use a proxy (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599933/how-to-use-an-http-proxy-in-java) for instance). Also, your code leaves many resources dangling, and you use `File` which is obsolete.

Here is how to do it in modern code:

```
final Path dstfile = Paths.get("h:", "abc.zip");

// ...

try (
    final InputStream in = url.openStream();
) {
    Files.copy(in, dstfile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
}
```

Comment: yes getting could not connect to the host .then how to use proxy seetings?can you help on that plzz?

Comment: Edited an answer to add a link for that; try and search around as well.