# How do I force Java applications to log onto a network proxy?

Tags: java, macos, minecraft

I am attempting to run  a Java application (specifically Minecraft) at my school on a mac computer. I wish to play online on my personal server, however the way the network is set up here the only way to access the internet is to enter network user/pass (The school uses a websense filter). Each student has one, and when you open a browser window a prompt will automatically ask me for it. The same user/pass is used to log into the machine, and some software will simply pick it up and go online without entering it a second time (ex. Safari just connects, Chrome however prompts for the user/pass).

Java applications however seem to be a mixed bag, some will connect, some will not. However none of them prompt me for the user/pass to the network.

So is there any way to force possibly through command line?) a Java application to log into the network?

Or is there possibly some other problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the proxy at the command line. This should help you: [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)

In case you can't use your proxy directly you might try and install a local proxy such as [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) that connects to your network proxy and authenticates using the credentials you provide. The application would then not have to provide credentials. However, you'd have to provide your network credentials to CNTLM and thus should not forget to remove them when you are done.