# Error when connecting to a website

Tags: java

I tried to run the following code :

```
public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        yc.connect();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

But the console displays nothing and when i tried to add `yc.connect` the console displayed the following errors:

```
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at internet01.URLConnectionReader.main(URLConnectionReader.java:18)
```

Update:
i connect to the internet through proxy.

Comment: you added permission on Internet in manifest??

Comment: try with  **yc.setDoOutput(true);** before connect.

Comment: @imperator: it's a java project not android

Comment: @priyank: i tried what diid u suggest but i receive the same errors

Comment: @imperator: sorry i removed the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting through proxy, JVM probably isn't aware of that.

Run you program with these arguments

`-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.ip -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxy.port`

Or set it within your program...

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm) by *Chris Carruthers*, *gr5*

Comment: sorry  but where should pass them?

Comment: `java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.ip -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxy.port URLConnectionReader`