# Permission denied using ant and scp

Tags: java, ant, java-7, scp

In my ant file, I scp a java war file to a test server.  As soon as I switched over to java 1.7, due to project requirements, the ant file is throwing a permission denied error:

BUILD FAILED

```
C:\Users\jdoe\Documents\code\build2\projectName\build.xml:72: com.jcraf
t.jsch.JSchException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:344)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:194)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHBase.openSession(SSHBas
e.java:223)
```

As soon as I switch back my JAVA_HOME environment variable back to Java 1.6 everything works fine.

I've tried installing two versions of java 7 (jdk1.7.0_03 and jdk1.7.0_11) but I am getting the same error with both of those versions.

the scp task in my build.xml file looks like this:

```
 <scp file="${name}.war" todir="${appserver.username}:${appserver.password}@${appserver.ipAddress}:${appserver.testTomcatLocation}" trust="yes"/>
```

I have the required jar file, jsch-0.1.49.jar located in my Ant path @ c:\Program Files(x86)\WinAnt\lib

Why isnt scp working when I am using Java 7.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client.  Turns out all I had to do was disable IPv6 in the VPN properties in Windows, the issue went away.  Here is the source on the internet that helped me: http://jonathangiles.net/blog/?p=1126

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering is perhaps you're sitting behind a corporate firewall?

Perhaps your Java 6 environment has some proxy settings that your new Java 7 installation is missing?

- [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)

Comment: The server that I am transferring the war file to is behind a VPN

Comment: I am looking at the JVM documentation now and I see this:
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=webcache.mydomain.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.noProxyHosts=”localhost|host.mydomain.com” GetURL

Is the proxyHost the ip address of the server that I am connecting to?

Comment: @majid If the server is running in a VPN then it's entirely feasible the proxy is the DMZ host that is exposed to the public network. You sure a proxy has been setup? I'd suggest investigating how Java6 was configured. If you find the proxy properties being set your questions will be answered.