# Eclipse Neon and Ant 1.9.6 using JCraft SSH Implementation

Tags: eclipse, ant

I changed my eclipse from kepler and ant 1.8.4 to neon and ant 1.9.6. If I run exactly the same project in Neon I got a ant build error by the following ant scp command:

```
<scp file="${jar.file}" todir="${user}@${host}:${destination.dir}/lib" keyfile="${privatekey}"
            passphrase="${passphrase}" sftp="true" trust="true" />
```

> BUILD FAILED C:\project\build.xml:31: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException:
>   Could not send 'source.jar' to '/target/lib' - 3: Permission denied

The funny thing is, at the end the file is on the server.
In both eclipse I add the library jsch-0.1.53.jar to the ant classpath.

Comment: Did you also changed Java from 1.6 to 1.8? If yes, see _[Permission denied using ant and scp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14490615/6505250)_

Comment: I am not changing the java version, both eclipse run with jdk 1.8. I installed ant 1.9.4 an set a new ant home under window > preferences >ant. And its working.

Answer (score -1):

@StellaMaris look at this bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59648

I'm using linux with Ant 1.8.4 and I have some target using scp, my colleagues running Windows, with Ant 1.9.5 have your problem and not only, it seems that Ant 1.9.5 has some regression in scp task.

Anyway the solution is using ANT 1.9.4, jsch 0.1.42 is good although [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies) states that minimum requirement is jsch 0.1.50

Comment: it should be a comment

Comment: I haven't enough reputation to comment sorry