# Java code to let users pass through ISA proxy Server providing ISA specific authentication(user&password)

Tags: java, proxy, httpwebrequest

Webpage to pass through ISA proxy server of our company
our company dedicated ISA proxy server to filter web surfing and also downloading and setting Quota by it.

The task how to make the user of my webpage surf the internet with full access.
given the below facility:
for example : if my windows userName : x and x is granted little permissions to surf and download from the internet , then I want my webpage to allow user to input the URL and then sending the HTTP request through the proxy with other user than X(x is the windows login user) , with the user (Y for example) who has full access to the internet … that means I have authentication (userName & password) which I want to put it as constants on my code to grant any user using my webpage full access to internet

How could I do such task?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm