# Java proxy settings - Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, proxy, network-programming

How do I set the Java proxy settings in Ubuntu (10.04 or 12.04), from the command line?
What I am aiming at is to get direct connection, but by default it takes it from browser settings which are meant to go via a proxy - just I don't want Java to go via the proxy.

I am running an application server in Ubuntu which serves remote desktop sessions. I can put the Java control panel into the user's desktop, and then they (each individual user) can set the proxy settings under Network Settings. However - this means I have to tell each user to make this setting, which is not workable.

I want it set via some command line or environment variable on the server itself, so it defaults to "direct connection". I am not familiar with Java programming and it won't help much to give me Java code for this, I think it must be possible to set the defaults upon Java startup? Any pointers are welcome.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can find the solution at this stack overflow answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm

Answer (score 5):

Instead of command line you can edit [`$javaDirectory/jre/lib/net.properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html).

Remove `#` in-front of:

```
http.proxyHost="proxy host"
http.proxyPort="proxy port"
https.proxyHost="proxy host"
https.proxyPort="proxy port"
```

and set your proxy there.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the **http_proxy** environment variable via command line.

Ex:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://proxy-server:port
```

There is a environment variable **ftp_proxy** also, just in case you need it.