# Error while opening a web link in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

i am trying to open a link in jeditorpane but i am getting the falling error

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
at GetWebPage.main(GetWebPage.java:7)**
```

below is my code

```
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GetWebPage {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        JEditorPane website = new JEditorPane("http://www.google.com/");
        website.setEditable(false);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(website));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is working fine on my side, please do check your internet settings...

Comment: Check the proxy setting if you are behind proxy

Comment: ohh i see let me check then

Comment: how can i set the proxy in code ?

Comment: @JavaNoob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. There is probably a problem with your DNS or proxy settings.

Comment: @JavaNoob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm