# Grails - proxy configuration

Tags: grails, proxy

In the ProxySettings.groovy file, how to specifiy 2 or more hosts in http.nonProxyHosts property ?

```
myproxy=['http.proxyHost':'proxy.mydomain.com', 'http.proxyPort':'8080', 'http.proxyUser':'XPTO', 'http.proxyPassword':'123456', 'http.nonProxyHosts': ??? ]
currentProxy="myproxy"
```

At ??? I tried the following with no effect:

```
['200.150.1.100', '201.160.1.200'] 
'200.150.1.100,201.160.1.200'
'200.150.1.100;201.160.1.200'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm) in the comments it looks like pipes (|) are the delimiter of choice.  try:

```
'200.150.1.100|201.160.1.200'
```