# Weblogic setting for proxy

Tags: java, proxy, weblogic, proxyselector

I have a problem with configuration of proxy to connect to `WebService` on `Weblogic 10.3.5.` I cannot use `System.setProperty()` because it has to be per connection aproach.
Proxy which I have to use has to have "`UserAgent`" header.

I have tried two options:

1. `ClientProxyFeature` but it doesn't work because it generate request
   to proxy without "UserAgent header".
2. `ProxySelector`: this approach work great on JUnit test but when I run
   it on Weblogic I receive following error

> error: java.net.SocketException: Unknown proxy type : HTTP at...

Is there any way to work this around?
Many Thanks in advance

Adam

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm

Comment: I cannot use System.setProperty() because it has to be per connection approach. From [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13941/weblogic/wsee/jaxws/proxy/ClientProxyFeature.html) I read that this can be done by using ClientProxyFeature class but the header of the request is not proper for proxy which I have to use (as I wrote I has to have "UserAgent" header and request from ClientProxyFeature doesn't have it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are able to do this with ProxySelector. The only thing which we have changed was server start parameter: -DUseSunHttpHandler=true. Now it works and send User-Agent header.

Answer (score 0):

To configure WebLogic proxy file is modified setDomainEnv.cmd (Windows) that is located in the bin folder of the domain.

For example for the integrated server is here

```
C: \ Users \ [YOUT USER NAME] \ AppData \ Roaming \ JDeveloper \ system11.1.1.4.37.59.23 \ DefaultDomain \ bin
```

The following property must be placed on file with the details of your proxy

```
@REM Estableciendo proxi 
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.101.11 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

See the next link

[Proxi in WebLogic](http://elektro2.blogspot.com/2013/01/configurar-proxy-en-weblogic-para.html)