# Trouble in calling webservice from Apache camel

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I am trying to call a web service from Apache Camel using CXF, that tries to convert the currency from one currency to other,  but I am unable to call it because of endpoint resolution. 
If any simple tutorials are there how to call webservices from Apache Camel please post..
Thanks in advance..

CamelContext is as below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd        
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring  
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

  <camelContext trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
    <from uri="file:src/data/order?noop=true"/>
        <log message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
        <to uri="cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdlURL=http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}CurrencyConvertor&amp;portName={http://www.webserviceX.NET/}CurrencyConvertorSoap&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>   
        <log message="&gt;&gt;&gt; ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

My order.xml is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
   <web:ConversionRate>
<web:FromCurrency>AUD</web:FromCurrency>
<web:ToCurrency>USD</web:ToCurrency>
</web:ConversionRate> 
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

This is the error i am facing while running the camel context ....

```
*************************************
Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.spring.Main
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:440)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[cxf://http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?dataFormat=MESSAGE&portName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.webserviceX.NET%2F%7DCurrencyConvertorSoap&serviceName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.webserviceX.NET%2F%7DCurrencyConvertor&wsdlURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webservicex.net%2FCurrencyConvertor.asmx%3Fwsdl]. Reason: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:395)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.acquireProducer(ProducerCache.java:114)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.startProducer(ProducerCache.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.doStart(TraceInterceptor.java:358)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.WrapProcessor.doStart(WrapProcessor.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1064)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:41)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:28)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:153)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:85)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:938)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.doStart(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:52)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:322)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:151)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:2000)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:1928)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1716)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1597)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1453)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStart(SpringCamelContext.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1421)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:283)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:475)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:186)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:141)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:332)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main(Main.java:73)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:398)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:534)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:248)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint.createClient(CxfEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.doStart(CxfProducer.java:76)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:393)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl'.: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.webservicex.net
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:249)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.webservicex.net
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:637)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at enter code herecom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
```

Comment: Essentially you are proxying the web service. See this example http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html

Comment: Thanks Namphibian for reply...Is the url framed in camel context is correct or wrong,because i am facing error in that url..

Answer (score 0):

When accessing `http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl` your log says:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
```

Check, if you have access to the internet. Or if you are behind a proxy server, you may first set the appropriate proxy settings. Find more information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm).

That said, your SOAP request misses the `web` namespace. Without the appropriate setting, the server will complain.

```
xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"
```

I started the tests with:

```
 final org.apache.camel.spring.Main main = new org.apache.camel.spring.Main();
 main.setApplicationContextUri("META-INF/spring/cxf-example.orig.xml");
 main.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Peter...I tried the things suggested by you both proxy and added xmlns in my camelcontext but still i am facing the same issue..

Comment: @Rahulbujji  I tested your set-up (with the corrected namespace declaration) and it worked correctly. If possible, test your route from a different server in another domain not behind the firewall.

Comment: Peter can you please post the camelcontext you tried..That will be useful to me...

Comment: @Rahulbujji I copy-pasted your example and only changed the file source location. I tested with Camel v2.12.3 and v2.13.1. I added my Java start sequence in my answer. However, as stated in my answer, I guess that your problem is network related.

Comment: @Rahulbujji Could you post how you set up the Camel proxy configuration?

Comment: @Rahulbujji See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm. I could not test it myself, but it should work.

Comment: @Rahulbujji If the answer helped you, you may mark it as correct.