# how to setup a libGDX project via proxy

Tags: java, proxy, libgdx

I am using the libgdx project creator (**gdx-setup.jar**) to setup a new project. However, I am using a proxy connection on my Windows machine to access the internet and the gdx-setup.jar isn't able to detect the settings, thus I cannot download the required jar files and generate any project. How and where do I change the java proxy settings so that I am able to achieve this?

PS: I have already tried to edit the settings under Control Panel->Java->Network Settings but to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

From Gradle's manual: [12.3. Accessing the web via a proxy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

You may need to create a $HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties file. For example:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=10.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.some.domain.com|localhost
```

IMPORTANT: There are separate settings for HTTPS.

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Then, just run setup like this:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -jar gdx-setup.jar
```

This works for me, behind a HTTP Proxy. Change it with your proxy settings.

Later, import your projects into Eclipse. And make sure your Eclipse Network Proxy is OK too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution:

http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16414&p=70348

For windows 7, gradle.properties is under C:\Users\USER_NAME.gradle\ (or create one if not exist)

Steps:
1. prepare gradle.properties file with following content

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms128m -Xmx1500m
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

2. run the jar through the same proxy

   java -Dhttp.proxyHost=**** -Dhttp.proxyPort=** -Dhttp.proxyUser=******** -Dhttp.proxyPassword=****  -jar gdx-setup.jar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14038201)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, really great

Comment: Upvote for a corrected answer. Believe me, it's frustrating when you're looking for solution, you find it and it occures, that the url is not active.

Answer (score 0):

If you run gdx-setup.jar from the command line, you should be able to tell the JVM to use the proxy settings using **http.proxyHost** and **http.proxyPort**.

See: [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm) for more information.

The command line would be something similar to:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -jar gdx-setup.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this problem using Eclipse with proxy configured in

Window -> Preferences -> Network Connections

I think it should be possible also in other IDEs or even Gradle (if you install it manually), provided that they have properly configured proxy.
This is because the Project Creator creates the whole directory structure, classes, etc., it fails later, when trying to download Gradle.
What I did after it failed is I went to Eclipse, I chose 'Import as Gradle project' and then clicked the Build Project button.
This downloaded Gradle and all the needed jars.