# How to send soap request through proxy server in java

Tags: java, http, soap, cxf, proxy-server

I am creating a simple `SOAP` client but my company has policy not to send SOAP request directly to the public server hence our company has a proxy server which runs on the some `IP` and port Now i have to send my `SOAP` request to this proxy server and than that server will forward it further. I am new to `SOAP`.

My question is: how can I connect to that proxy server and can send the `SOAP` request to it?? I am using `CXF` lib. for `SOAP`.

Comment: I am using CXF lib for SOAP

Comment: Looks like duplicate of [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setProxyServer(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));
    policy.setProxyServerPort(Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort")).intValue());

    httpConduit.setClient(policy);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Its giving Connection Refused error.When i am sending the SOAP request through java client.But when I am sending SOAP request through SOAP ui its getting successful.