# Red5 demo apps showing error

Tags: red5

I am getting following while connecting to red5 demo apps :

> NetConnection.Connect.Closed
>
> [WARN] [ConnectionChecker-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Connection GN0PSGBZE63TF has exceeded the max inactivity threshold of 60000 ms
>
> [INFO] [NioProcessor-5] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection is closed:
>
> [WARN] [NioProcessor-5] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Connection was not found for GN0PSGBZE63TF
>
> [ERROR] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-3] org.red5.server.service.ServiceInvoker - Method getApplicationList with parameters [] not found in org.red5.server.Context@4989fa8
>
> [WARN] [RTMPConnectionExecutor-3] org.red5.server.service.ServiceInvoker - Service not found: installer
>
> [WARN] [ConnectionChecker-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Connection Q6TFXYIXBD4T4 has exceeded the max inactivity threshold of 60000 ms
>
> [INFO] [NioProcessor-9] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection - Connection is closed:
>
> [WARN] [NioProcessor-9] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Connection was not found for Q6TFXYIXBD4T4
>       [root@vps red5]# ^C

Answer (score 0):

A few things are happening here:

1. Your client connection is timing out
2. The method you attempted to call doesn't exist
3. The installer service isn't installed or running

Obviously I dont know what happened before the first line "NetConnection.Connect.Closed" so I can't assume much about that missing section. To fix 1-3, you probably just need to add the installer app to your install. Grab all the stuff in this location and put it in your red5/webapps/installer directory: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/tree/master/src/main/server/webapps/installer

Comment: Yes I have tried installer but still suffers with same issue

Comment: If you're not testing this locally, try setting proxy properties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm