# How to use HttpsConnection in java via proxy?

Tags: java, https, proxy

I am using below code

```
    URL obj = new URL("https://www.example.com/profile");
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(Ip, port));
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection(proxy);    

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

But I am not able to get data from web page.
Please suggest how can I use the Proxy to fetch data from Https urls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not error but I am not getting any output ,String inputLine;
  

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   response.append(inputLine);
  }
  in.close();
  
  } Response is empty, also tried to read con.getErrorStream(), response is empty

Comment: this may useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm