# Java Image Grab and Display

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to grab an image from online, and then use it to display on a Jframe form. The "Hello, World!" will display, but the image won't display. Any ideas guys? Cheers.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello, World!");
    String path = "http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=GOOG&t=6m&q=l";
            try {
                URL url = new URL(path);
                ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(url);
                JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
                label.setOpaque(true);
                frame.add(imageLabel);
                frame.add(label);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Comment: Please have a look here [ask] - you need to include errors if there are any or tell us that there aren't any - cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The `JFrame` is using a `BorderLayout` by default, which means only one component can be shown at the (default) `CENTER` position.

Basically, what's happening is the `label` is superseding the `imageLabel` and is been displayed instead, try doing something like..

[image: Example]

```
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
label.setOpaque(true);
frame.add(imageLabel);
//frame.add(label);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

See [How to use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details

I would also use `ImageIO.read` of `ImageIcon` to the load, at least it will throw a `IOException` when the image can't be loaded, see [Reading/loading images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are behind a proxy server and your code is not able to connect to `chart.finance.yahoo.com`

Please add proxy settings to your program by putting actual values

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<your proxy ip>");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<proxy port>");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "<proxy user>");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "<proxy password>");
```

Alternatively you can provide these as commandline arguments as well using `-D` switch. For more details please see: [How to use proxy from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)