# Calling openStream() throws java.net.ConnectException exception: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, connectionexception

```
public String  pdfReadData() throws Exception
{
String pdfText = null;
try
{
    driver.get("https://www.....pdf");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    URL url= new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    BufferedInputStream fileToParse = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    System.out.println("step1");
    PDFParser parser= new PDFParser(fileToParse);
    parser.parse();
    COSDocument cosDocument  = parser.getDocument();
    PDDocument pdDocument = new PDDocument(cosDocument);
    if(pdDocument.isEncrypted()) 
    {
        StandardDecryptionMaterial sdm  = new StandardDecryptionMaterial(PDF_OWNER_PASSWORD);
        pdDocument.openProtection(sdm); // org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException: Error: The supplied password does not match either the owner or user password in the document.
        //pdDocument.decrypt(objConfigurationFile.PDF_OWNER_PASSWORD)// the same like above
    }
    pdfText= new PDFTextStripper().getText(pdDocument);
    System.out.println("pdf Value" + pdfText);
    // parser.getPDDocument.close();
    //parser.

    // driver.manage.timeouts.implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
catch (MalformedURLException e2)
{
    System.err.println("URL string could not be parsed "+e2.getMessage());
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}
return pdfText;
}
```

}

Running this code in eclipse launches the URL with pdf document, and then give the below exception. The same set of code was running in scala in same machine.Couldnt figure out why this is happening.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at projectSpecificFunctions.ProjectSpecificLayer.pdfReadData(ProjectSpecificLayer.java:229)
at stepDefinitionAndRunner.rub3810_1.a_MLC_Plum_customer_has_logged_into_MLC_Plum_secure_site(rub3810_1.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Are you in a company? You do probably have to use a proxy. If yes, search for: java openStream proxy. This has nothing to do with PDFBox.

Comment: I've changed the title... although your question is likely a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Tilman.Yes..I work in a company. I have the http_proxy and https_proxy set up in System environment variables. Do I need to add some other settings too?

Comment: To be sure that proxy is really set up correctly, make a test with openStream() on a website you known to be accessible, e.g. http://google.com .

Comment: Don't forget the port: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost","127.0.0.1" );
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort","3128" );
```

Adding this line of code before the code above solved the issue.