# Connection timeout while reading mails via Javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, redhat

Am trying to read mails from our mail server using Javamail api. The program works fine when am running it on eclipse in windows on my local system. 
When i move the same code to our linux environment it gets connection timed out error.

Do i need to install some package on linux or anything? I believe the port should be open else i wont be able to connect from my local network?

The code am using is as below:

```
properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
properties.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");
session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
store = session.getStore();
store.connect(mailServerName, userName, password);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have first to check if you allowed to connect to your mail server from your lunix host , by issuing `telnet`  like this : `telnet host port`command , some times it is either blocked by firewall or network antivirus. also you may behind a proxy server (You have to check all the above with your network admin).

In case you are behind a proxy server, you have to set the proxy settings and credntials for the JVM. For this , look at  answer at [Chris Carruthers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)
 here.

Comment: See also the [connection debugging tips in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: We came to know from admin that we didn't have access to the mail server.