# Global configuration of http proxy in camel

Tags: proxy, apache-camel, jbossfuse, camel-http

So far, I have learned to ways to set HTTP proxy with camel.

- First one is to append proxy information with destination URI

  ```
  <to uri="http://sample.com?proxyAuthHost=proxy.example.com&amp;proxyPort=8080"/>
  ```
- Other approach is setting proxy global to `CamelContext`

  ```
  <properties>
      <property key="http.proxyHost" value="proxy.example.com"/>
      <property key="http.proxyPort" value="8080"/>
  </properties>
  ```

  Other than these approaches, is there any way by which I can configure proxy globally so that, I don't have repeat this procedure for each `URI` or for each `CamelContext`? For example, if I configure proxy in a properties file, how can I use it(Other than using property using `{{key}}` approach)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should edit the **setenv** file of Karaf, located in `bin/` folder under your JBoss Fuse installation. In that file, add the properties linked by Claus' answer to EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS variable.

On Linux edit `bin/setenv`

```
EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800"
export EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS
```

On Windows edit `bin/setenv.bat`

```
SET EXTRA_JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800
```

Then start JBoss Fuse, those options will be added to Java command line by `bin/fuse` script.

`bin/fuse` script calls `bin/karaf` which imports such variable from `bin/setenv`.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the http proxy settings as JVM parameters. There is other SO questions about this such as: [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am deploying my project on JBOSS Fuse. In that case, where should I set the proxy?