# HttpURLConnection connect method fails to connect

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

```
SocketAddress proxy = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080);
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.1/");

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxy));
connection.setDoOutput(true);
String body = "This is a body example";

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()), "8859_1");
writer.write(body);
writer.flush();
writer.close();

connection.connect();
```

The problem is that when I run this code no requests are "catched" by my proxy (it is well configured). I know connect() is an abstract method in URLConnection but given that HttpURLConnection is extending URLConnection it is suppose to override it. This is what javadoc say about connect() : "Opens a communications link to the resource referenced by this URL, if such a connection has not already been established." So the request should have been sent. Anyone know what causes the problem?

NOTE : If I replace connection.connect() with connection.getResponseHeader() I catch a request. As I have read in javadoc if the connection is not set yet a call to getResponseHeader() will call implicitly the connect() method.

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32897878/584420

Comment: @JamesJithin Proxy is not my problem because as post says "If I replace connection.connect() with connection.getResponseHeader(), connection establishes and the request is getting catched"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is what javadoc say about connect() : "Opens a communications link to the resource referenced by this URL, if such a connection has not already been established."

Correct.

> So the request should have been sent.

*Non sequitur.* Thwre is nothing in your quotation about sending the request.

As you have observed, the request is buffered until you perform some input step.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured it out that there is a TCP handshake that establishes. Actually Ι think that this is kind of unnecessary because TCP connection maybe timeout on the server side. Thanks anyway.