# how to use proxy in OCSP request

Tags: java, proxy, ocsp

I need to validate X509 Certificate using OCSP using http proxy. Here is my code:

```
                List<X509Certificate> certificates = Collections.singletonList(certificate);
            CertPath cp = factory.generateCertPath(certificates);
            Set<TrustAnchor> trust = new HashSet<>();
            trust.add(new TrustAnchor(issuerCertificate, null));
            PKIXParameters params = new PKIXParameters(trust);
            params.setRevocationEnabled(true);
            CertPathValidator cpv =
                    CertPathValidator.getInstance(CertPathValidator.getDefaultType());

            PKIXCertPathValidatorResult validationResult =
                    (PKIXCertPathValidatorResult) cpv.validate(cp, params);
```

I know, that I can set proxy using
System.setProperty("http.proxy", "...") but I need to set it only for my request, not for whole system.

Comment: Just to prevent mistakes: the java property for configuring the proxy is *not* `http.proxy`. It is `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/120802/4864870.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to write own OCSP verification code based on one of Apache Open Source projects [Apache Open Source projects](https://apache.googlesource.com/synapse/+/25087a1cf40335230f9674f023ff62a1408d8908/java/modules/transports/core/nhttp/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/utils/sslcert/ocsp/OCSPVerifier.java)
and extend it to use configurable HTTP proxy for request