# HTTPUrlConnection is returning 400 for Linux but works on Windows

Tags: java, api, networking, twitch

I am making a request to twitch api with the following code

```
    URL url = new URL("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?channel=" + channelID)
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Client-ID", clientID);

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append("\r");
    }
    br.close();
    return response.toString();
```

This gets the correct response on windows, however when i run it on my Raspberry PI it gets a 400 response. I found a [similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695299/java-httpurlconnection-works-on-windows-and-fails-on-linux) i tried to set the proxy settings with this code

```
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```

However this failed to fix this request, any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone comes accross this problem in the future, i upgraded to java 11 and implemented it using [http client in java 11](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) i have no idea at all why this fixes the issue but it does.