# WireMock Proxy different requests to different hosts to record response

Tags: testing, integration-testing, wiremock

I am using wireMock to record response from another module, My application is consuming data from so many modules, so I want to record all the responses at a time, Currently, I am trying to record response one by one at a time, with the below command, which is eating lot of time

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx.xx.xx.xx -Dhttp.proxyPort=xx -Dhttps.proxyHost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx -Dhttps.proxyPort=xx -jar wiremock-standalone-2.4.1.jar --proxy-all="https://xxx-ppe.api.xxx.com" --record-mappings --verbose
```

Can someone help me how to proxy all those hosts at a time and how to record all of them at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [Traffic Parrot Community Edition](http://trafficparrot.com) instead of Wiremock. The community edition is a free version based on Wiremock. It just has more functionality.

To record many hosts at the same time:

- In the Traffic Parrot menu open HTTP->HTTP Proxy, click record and start.
- Set up your [system](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-proxy-environment-variable/) or [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm) to use a HTTP proxy localhost:8095
- Optional: if you are sending HTTPS requests you need to [set up the certificates](http://trafficparrot.com/documentation/3.10.x/http.html#http-proxy-link)
- The http proxy recorder will now record both HTTP and HTTPS traffic for all hostnames (for example a whole website, or mobile application connecting to many systems at the same time).

[image]