# Does the JVM use the system proxy settings under Raspbian?

Tags: java, proxy, ftp, jvm, raspbian

First up I want to describe my problem.
I created a program which connects directly to a FTP-Server.
Now I need to make it run behind a proxy as well.

While searching around I've found this thread: [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)

As I understood, it is sufficient (under Raspbian) to set

> export ftp_proxy="http://username:password@host:port/"

in /etc/environment

and write `System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");` into my code to make the program use the proxy.

Am I right?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: not yet. At first I wanted to know whether I'm totally wrong or not

Comment: stackoverflow is not really the place where you go and ask "will this work" before you even tried anything... :-O But yes, in general, what you read there makes sense. This system property (`java.net.useSystemProxies`) will probably switch on usage of these proxy variables.

Comment: the problem is that I can't really try it right away.

Comment: Because on my developing network theirs no proxy so a direct connection is enough

Comment: But if people think this might be a good way to go I'll try it soon on the live-system

Comment: See this article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html