# Micronaut CLI behind a HTTP proxy

Tags: micronaut

I'm new to Micronaut, and Gradle for that matter, and I was able to get it to work on my personal laptop. But I wanted to get a POC working for work which is behind a HTTP proxy.

I've been looking for some examples on how to configure Micronaut to be able to work properly behind it. Can anybody point me to some docs or examples to show how this is done?

P.S. I've been trying to get some Gradle examples into an init.d directory in Micronaut hoping it would pick it up but I haven't gotten it to work yet.

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only with the proxy, you can search for how to configure a proxy for a java project - you will find tons of resources. For instance this SO question might help:
[How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)

Answer (score 0):

I did an

> export MN_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.proxyUser=test -Dhttp.proxyPassword=test"

analog to

> export GRAILS_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.proxyUser=test -Dhttp.proxyPassword=test"

http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#proxyConfig

It's undocumented in micronaut but it worked for me on RC1

Good luck

---

correction:
It is in the sources

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/master/src/main/docs/guide/cli/proxy.adoc

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/commit/63e18d8d3

It's just not yet in the generated docs