# Unable to install micronaut on windows 10

Tags: micronaut

I downloaded micronaut 1.04 binary. I specified MICRONAUT_HOME environment variable and updated path. When I type mn, I get the following error:

| Error Error occurred running Micronaut CLI: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

I am behind proxy and set up all right proxy variables for java (http_proxy, https_proxy, proxyHost, proxyPort in -D variables, etc.) Can someone tell me how should I proceed in windows?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672417/micronaut-cli-behind-a-http-proxy

Comment: I tried everything. My problem is with certification path being invalid.

Comment: I even went ahead and used keytool to import our companies certificate to cacerts. Still no help. I don't know what #micronaut is looking for.

Comment: @mikeb Likely it's failing to connect to `https://jcenter.bintray.com`

Comment: You were right. It was bintray. I thought it was github. Anyway, after saving certificate using keytool, now it works. This is a painful way of doing it. I don't know why they are not packaging the complete package for windows install. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen if you are behind a VPN/Firewall that filters HTTPS. Try to load the Firewall's certificates on your JDK cacerts or try to run the command outside the VPN/Firewall.