# HttpURLConnection to HTTPs with proxy

Tags: java, https, proxy

I want to connect to an `https://` URL in Java that requires proxy.

I have 2 proxies in the system:

```
HTTP  -> proxy.teatre.guerrilla:8080
HTTPS -> proxy.teatre.guerrilla:8443
```

I've tried with

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.teatre.guerrilla", 8080));

URL url = new URL ( urlStr);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

But I got a `Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

and I haven't seen the type `Proxy.Type.HTTPS`

I also tried

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.teatre.guerrilla");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy.teatre.guerrilla");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8443");
```

with the same result.

I also tried to add this as Program arguments and VM arguments....

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.teatre.guerrilla -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.teatre.guerrilla -Dhttps.proxyPort=8443
```

Comment: looks like you tried to make an HTTP request to the proxy itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.teatre.guerrilla");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", 8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

You better not include proxy handling in your code. You never know in which environment your JAVA application will be running. So please configure the PROXY settings with JVM args like that: [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)