# How can i set a global variable for Java so that it puts all java applets through a proxy?

Tags: java, c#, proxy, minecraft

I am trying to figure out how to make it so all java applications running on the machine are put through a provided proxy. I am doing this because the application that will be running does not support proxies by default and due to the circumstance i can not just give it command arguments. Below is what I have found so far and I have triied both the _JAVA_OPTIONS, JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, and _JPI_VM_OPTIONS. The application I am trying to work with is minecraft.

Prior to this issue I couldnt determine why my proxy application that I have built in C# using Titanium Web Proxy was not picking up on the minecraft traffic, and I have come to the conclusion that it is because it is not using the system's proxy. Here are the commands I have used to try setting the variable that are still not causing the JVM to go through the proxy.

- set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
- set _JPI_VM_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
- set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true

Guess my question is , is this possible?

> If you find yourself using the same options over and over before laucing a java process, you can set up a special environment variable to contain your default options and the JVM will pick up the the values.
> If the Java process is launch via java.exe then the environment variable is called _JAVA_OPTIONS (see JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS below for a better option),
>
> e.g. In Windows:
>
> set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms64m -Xmx128m -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
> In Linux:
> export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xms64m -Xmx128m -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd'
> ref : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html
> If the Java process is launch via javaw.exe (Applet) then the environment variable is called
> _JPI_VM_OPTIONS.
>
> For example :
>
> _JPI_VM_OPTIONS = -Dsome.property=true
> For a Java Web Start process (javaws.exe), the environment variable is called JAVAWS_VM_ARGS.
>
> For example :
>
> JAVAWS_VM_ARGS = -Dsome.property=true
> But .. The preferred way is to use an environment called JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.
> _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable was ok but was not documented or supported. Since it is not >standardized, other vendors have their own names e.g. IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS. Leading underscore names are >private by convention so it's not a good to standardize the usage of _JAVA_OPTIONS. That's why >JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS should be the preferred choice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question on the `Arqade` (another StackExchange site) can help: [How can I play Minecraft through a proxy server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/21848);
or, among others on StackOverflow, [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120797/13510609)

Basically setting `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to include `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyURL -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPORT -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyURL -Dhttps.proxyPort=proxyPORT`

(`java.net.useSystemProxies` should also work... but maybe minecraft (starter) is not *respecting*  these settings - I believe you can set options in the starter as well)

Comment: Damn. So I have tried setting this by hand in command prompt and then trying it with the proxy and it still doesnt work. I feel like I am missing something extremely simple. Could I just do something simialr with a HTTP Listener?