# Is it possible to configure log4j to use a proxy are part of its connections out to Splunk, Datadog, etc?

Tags: log4j

If log4j doesn't support this then is there some drop-in replacement for log4j that does?  I've gone through the docs and lots of google searches, unfortunately all search results come up with "exploit" or "vulnerability" articles.

Answer (score 0):

Splunk provides a [`splunk-library-javalogging`](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-library-javalogging) that has appenders for both Log4j2 Core (the reference Log4j2 API implementation) and Logback (the reference SLF4J API implementation).

The appenders use OkHttp 3.x under the hood, so they will behave as all OkHttp-based components. Since `splunk-library-javalogging` does not set either a [`proxy`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/proxy/) nor a [`proxySelector`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/proxy-selector/) explicitly (cf. [source code](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-library-javalogging/blob/bf54f1db4740e7570fbd8e36536d28e300846ecf/src/main/java/com/splunk/logging/HttpEventCollectorSender.java#L332)), OkHttp falls back to the system wide [`ProxySelector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html#getDefault--).

Without any code modification on your part you can use the JVM-wide proxy settings as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/120797/11748454).

**Remark**: if by `log4j` you are referring to Log4j 1.x, you need to replace the `log4j:log4j` artifact with either [`log4j-over-slf4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j) (which forwards to the SLF4J API) or [`log4j-1.2-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api) (which forwards to the Log4j2 API).