# How to make a portable installation of Java use system proxies?

Tags: java, proxy, proxyselector

I need to connect using proxy.
It only works when I add `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` to commandline.
The problem is that it works only with installed java on computer, and I also need to run my program on computers with I would say portable java (folder JRE is copied and virtual machine is running using `jre/bin/java.exe` command.
In this case, `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` is not taken into account and I am not able to connect using proxy.

API I use to connect is:

```java
List<Proxy> proxxies = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI(serverURL));
```

Without `property` set to `true`, I don't receive a list of proxies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the proxy to be used by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120797/how-do-i-set-the-proxy-to-be-used-by-the-jvm)

Comment: Unfortunately not. -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true works on some computers on others not. Why ?

Comment: I'm asking if setting it as an environmental variable and/or using the -Dhttp.proxyHost works. Is the answer to both no?