how to capture traffic of grpc client and server using mitmproxy
I have a grpc bidirectional client and server, with server running on localhost. I saw the official docs on how to use mitmproxy. The demo used curl command with --proxy flag to configure mitmproxy as a proxy. But in my case Im running client and server jars using java -jar Client.jar/Server.jar command. My question is how to configure my client, server and mitmproxy to capture the http2 bidirectional streams.

You can try it to specify as -D option as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/120802/150978 But I am not sure if gRPC library will respect proxy settings.

Hi Robert, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but I couldn't see any http2 traffic being captured by mitmproxy.
