# java scp problem

Tags: java, networking, servlets, jakarta-ee, scp

I am having a situation here which I need to resolve. I have to upload particular elements of an xml file to upload it to a server, managed to do that, and I created a demo method to check if the file is being uploaded to the server or not.

My xml file has the structure,

```
<config>
 <engine>
    <eid>1</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>

 <engine>
    <eid>2</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>

 <engine>
    <eid>3</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>


</config>
```

and here is my servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        //response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
         String value = request.getParameter("value");
            String message = "";
            String update = "";
            Element element = null;
            Element root = null;
            XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter();
        try{
        doc = saxBuilder.build("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/engine.xml");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        root = doc.getRootElement();
        List list = doc.getRootElement().getChildren();
        Iterator itr = list.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
             element = (Element)itr.next();
            System.out.println("Entered 1");
          File f = File.createTempFile("engine_",".xml");
           System.out.println(f);
            xmlOutputter.output(element, new FileWriter(f));

            putFile(f);
        }



         // xmlOutputter.output(doc, new FileWriter("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/engine.xml"));





        // System.out.println("hello from system");
        // out.println("hello");



    }

    public void putFile(File f){
         System.out.println("File String: "+f.toString());
         Connection Conn = null;
          try {
           Conn = new Connection("ftp.someserver.co.uk",22);
           ConnectionInfo info = Conn.connect();
           Conn.authenticateWithPassword("webmaster@someserver.co.uk", "mypass");
           SCPClient SCP = new SCPClient(Conn);
           SCP.put(f.toString(), "/public_html/webmaster", "0755");
           Conn.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
           try {
            Conn.close();
           } catch (Exception e1) {}
    }
    }
```

Now, From the above code I am getting file created for engine 1, engine 2 and engine 3, and thats what I wanted, but now I want it to upload to the server too. and the putFile code is not working at all.The port is also perfect. Whats wrong then?
any ideas?

Heres the error:

```
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to ftp.someserver.co.uk:22
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:699)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:490)
    at Push_Individual_Engine.putFile(Push_Individual_Engine.java:106)
    at Push_Individual_Engine.doPost(Push_Individual_Engine.java:81)
    at Push_Individual_Engine.doGet(Push_Individual_Engine.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.establishConnection(TransportManager.java:340)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.initialize(TransportManager.java:448)
    at ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:643)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Can you connect with simpler tools? `telnet ftp.someserver.co.uk 22` or `nc ftp.someserver.co.uk 22` or `ssh ftp.someserver.co.uk`?

Comment: have you checked the answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86824/why-would-a-java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-exception-occur-whe) out?

Comment: it's just a simple tool that can report if the host and port combination works; `telnet localhost 22` on my machine returns: `... Connected to localhost.localdomain. ... SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5`. Use Control+`]` to bring up the menu, then `quit<enter>` to quit telnet again. The `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH...` banner from my machine's `sshd` shows the version number I'm running. You might also get `Connection refused` (port not open), `Name or service not known` (invalid hostname), etc. The `telnet(1)` isn't nearly as important as using a second tool to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned this error usually occurs either if Ip/domain name or port is incorrect, did you try doing a telnet from the same box as your java program is running on? Could be a firewall issue if port and name are ok or a dns issue if your box cant resolve the domain correctly.

Comment: I never used telnet, could you tell me more about it.

Comment: it is a command you can run from a command prompt, either a dos command prompt or a linux command prompt. It will basically attempts to open a socket to your remote server and will let you know if you cant you would call it using telnet <server> <ip>