# Two Visual Studios installed: VS2015 and VS2017. In VS2017, I am facing problems while viewing activity_main.xml

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, renderer

I have installed xamarin in VS2015 and VS2017 both.I am facing some package issues in VS2015 and in VS2017 I am getting renderer problem.

In VS2017, I am facing problems while viewing  `activity_main.xml` file as

Connection to layout renderer failed. This may be caused due to misconfiguration of java.

Details are as follow:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at mono.android.HostProcessConnection.Connect(HostProcessConnection.java:23)
    at mono.android.AndroidDesignerHost.run(AndroidDesignerHost.java:58)
    at mono.android.AndroidDesignerHost.main(AndroidDesignerHost.java:47)
```

Please see the image below:

Answer (score 0):

This is not misconfigured java, but networking problem[s].

Search after "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" shows some relevant SO answers:

[Why would a "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out" exception occur when URL is up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86824/why-would-a-java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-exception-occur-wh)

Set your timeout to some higher value